Unwanted characters in Google Merchant Center feed product descriptions
Having an issue where product descriptions on Google Merchant Center are showing like this  with the html included. Anyone know how I go about fixing this? I use CTX Feed via Woocommerce to pull in products and have already re-processed and uploaded it again.
I have the same setup for another site and it's is fine.

Have you tried this free woocommerce product feed plugin ?

Did you check the documentation and guides from CTX feed? How to remove Short Codes and HTML tags from product description.
